# How to add macOS certification to Delphi 10.3.1 MacOS app's

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey

How to add MacOS certification to Delphi MacOS app (Normal Buld Type).

For IOS applications I choose the Provision Profile from Options-Deployment-Provisioning.

For MacOS I can only choose Build Type here.

Comment: Can a 32 bit app be certified?

Comment: I do not know. I've never done it. The idea is that there will be no problem running this application without downloading from the AppStore.

Comment: If you want to certify an app, then isn't the onus on you to check whether or not your app meets the criteria?  So far as I know, MacOS apps these days must be 64 bit.  Yours is not because your Delphi doesn't have the 64 bit Mac OS compiler.

Comment: You're right, I didn't check. I thought it was the same as with IOS. Thank you for the information.
In that case, how to prepare MACOS applications in Delphi so that it can be run on all MAC computers. There is a problem for new ones mac versions. Apps cannot be started because they are not from APPSTORE and are not certified

Comment: You can still execute uncertified apps on a mac. But they'll have to be 64Bit for Catalina and the user will have to allow/enable execution of unsigned apps.

Comment: Realistically you will want to upgrade to the latest version of Delphi and port your app to 64 bit. That's the first step. After that, how you go about certifying, I'm not sure.

Comment: Generally the problem is like here.   https://superuser.com/questions/1345755/how-to-fix-the-application-cant-be-opened-on-mac. I will try everything that is described here.  Thanks for the help !

Comment: @HerMajestyQueenofARC Don't think so. Was added in 10.3.2. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/10.3_Rio_-_Release_2, or am I reading the version numbers incorrectly?

Comment: 10.3.1 has only 32bit MacOS version

Comment: If it is built with 10.3.1, and you mean "notarization" rather than "certification", then it is impossible, since Delphi 10.3.1 produces 32-bit macOS apps. If your users upgrade to macOS 10.15 they will not be able to run your app; you will need Delphi 10.3.2, compile for 64-bit and notarize the app